# How can I access private class using assembly.getype() in System.Reflection.Assembly Class C#

Tags: c#, class, private, system.reflection

I am using following code to load private class B from "X.Y.Z.dll" but it is throwing could not load assembly type ,

```
 Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(CurrentExecutingDirectory + "X.Y.Z.dll");
 Type serviceHelper = asm.GetType("X.Y.Z.A.B", true);
```

please give some  idea to achieve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact Exception? Is there an InnerException containing mor information?

Answer (score 3):

Use `+` as the separator between nested and containing class:

```
Type serviceHelper = asm.GetType("X.Y.Z.A+B", true);
```

Alternatively, enumerate all contained types with `GetTypes()` and pick the one you want:

```
Type serviceHelper = asm.GetTypes().First(t => t.IsNestedPrivate && t.Namespace == "X.Y.Z" && t.Name = "B");
```

Comment: First, thanks for teaching me something! Not only does it work just like you say, but I am gobsmacked not only to be able to discover the private class but to _instantiate_ it as well. ` var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typePrivate);` What good is private then??

Comment: @IVSoftware access modifiers are basically just compiler hints. Reflection API allows you to bypass all the rules the compiler would've enforced 

Comment: Thanks @Mathias It worked. just encountered one more issue as I am trying to access private constructor using this code , ConstructorInfo privateConstructor = serviceHelper.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(Ssn), typeof(long) }, null);  But I am getting private constructor as null. Could you please help me in this?